# Basic assembly calculator

Tags: assembly, x86

Please help me with this program! I have spent a lot of time on reading documents, but I don'y quite understand why my codes don't work. It's just a basic calculator and this is what I have so far. After the second method, none of them works. Thank you!

```
int calc (int op1, int op2, int opcode)
{
__asm
{
mov eax, 0       ; zero out the result
mov ebx, opcode  ; move opcode to ebx for comparison
cmp ebx, 0x01    ; check for ADD
jne sub_2        ; jump if not 2 to sub
mov eax, op1     ; move op1 into eax
add eax, op2     ; add op2 into eax
jmp done         ;    jump to done
sub_2:
cmp ebx, 0x02    ;
jne mul_3        ;jump if not 3 to mul
mov eax, op1     ;move op1 into eax
sub eax, op2     ;subtract op2 into eax
jmp done         ; jump to done
mul_3:
cmp ebx, 0x03    ;
jne div_4        ; jump to div_4 if ot 3
mov eax, 0       ; move 0 into eax
mov ecx, op1     ; move op1 into ecx  
mov edx, op2     ; move op2 into edx    
L2:   
//and ecx, 01    ; I'm not sure if I should do this to check the lowest bit
jnc no_add       ; check if lowest bit is 0, if yes jump to no_add    
add eax, edx     ; add edx to the result which is eax   
no_add:    
rcr ecx, 1       ; rotate with carry to right 1 bit ecx   
shl edx, 1       ; shift left edx 1 bit  
jnz L2           ; jump back to loop if edx is not 0   
jmp done

done:
```

}

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of commenting your code?

Comment: share your error trace

Comment: @SSH I'm really new to assembly code, so I just did what the documents say and don't understand why they don't work.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I'm very new to these stuffs, so that I don't know why they don't work. Can you guys help please?

Comment: @baopham I don't know why it doesn't work either, but faced with over 100 lines of code with no hint of what each section is supposed to do and no clear indication of what the problem is I'm not minded to try to find out.

Comment: Sorry about it. Let's me edit it again, and pleas take a look.

Comment: See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @HoboSapiens can you help me with it please?

Answer (score 1):

In assembly; all bugs can be classified as either:

- comments for each line (when read in order) don't describe a sane algorithm, or
- the instruction on a line doesn't match its comment

For example, these comments don't describe a sane algorithm for addition, and the bug is obvious from reading the comments alone:

```
;Do addition

mov eax,op1        ;eax = operand1
sub eax,op2        ;eax = operand1 - operand2 = result
```

For another example, these instructions don't match the comments, and the bug is obvious from comparing each instruction to its comment:

```
;Do addition

mov eax,op1        ;eax = operand1
add eax,op2        ;eax = operand1 + operand2 = result
```

This practice makes it much much easier to find bugs because you can check the algorithm much easier, and then (if/when you're sure the algorithm is correct) check the implementation much easier.

For your code, the comments don't describe a sane algorithm and the instructions don't match their comments; so your code is 100% bugs.

Note that assembly language is not one language. There are one or more different dialects of assembly language for each CPU. For 80x86 there's are 2 groups of assembly languages (AT&T syntax and Intel syntax); and within each group there are incompatible dialects. For example; code written for NASM/YASM will often not assemble correctly on FASM or MASM (even though they all use Intel syntax); because things like directives (and in some cases operands) are different.

For example, I saw `mov eax,op1` in your code, and because I'm used to NASM syntax I assumed that it's a bug (using the address and not the data at the address) and should be `mov eax,[op1]` instead. However, for MASM (which likes to try to make it look more like variables in higher level languages) `mov eax,op1` may be perfectly correct and not a bug. Because you haven't indicated which dialect of assembly you're using, I can't tell if this is a bug or not.

When you have a long chain of branches, it's more efficient (and easier to read/maintain the code) to use a jump table. For example (NASM syntax):

```
    section .data
    dd .doAddition, .doSubtraction, .doMultiplication, .doDivision
%define MAX_OPCODES  4
    section .text

    mov ebx,[opcode]          ;ebx = next opcode
    cmp ebx,MAX_OPCODE        ;Is the opcode too large for the jump table?
    jae .error                ; yes, error
    jmp [opcodeTable + ebx*4] ; no, jump to the code that handles this opcode

.doAddition:
    ; Code to do addition here!
    jmp .done

.doSubtraction:
    ; Code to do subtraction here!
    jmp .done

.doMultiplication:
    ; Code to do multiplication here!
    jmp .done

.doDivision:
    ; Code to do division here!
    jmp .done
```